# How to get Id of clicked input created at runtime

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to add some submit input to my page at run time and use the Id of the clicked input in an event handler.

Here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="CNT1" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH1">
    <div id ="CNT" runat="server">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<script language="c#" runat="server">


private void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = ((HtmlInputSubmit) sender).ID;
    // some other code using id 
}
</script>
```

and here is my aspx.cs code

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    CNT.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
    "<input type=\"submit\" runat=\"server\" id="+dr.ItemArray[0].ToString()+
        " value=\"val1\" OnServerClick=\"btnClick\"/>"));
}
```

I can use this code to create my inputs on the aspx page without any problems.

Comment: what is the question? is this not working "string id = ((HtmlInputSubmit) sender).ID;"?

Comment: please be more specific, unable to understand the problem

Comment: try to checkout your button_click event is fired or not?

Comment: this codes are not working

Comment: how can i check button_click event ?

Comment: Use `GridView` or some data listing controls with button column and assign your `DataTable` as it's `DataSource`. This will generate server side buttons for each row

Answer (score 0):

Change access modifier from private to protected:

```
protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = ((HtmlInputSubmit) sender).ID;
    // some other code using id 
}
```

Because the private member function can't be accessed.

Comment: it is valuable for me to know why my codes are not working .

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.predictions_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.

Comment: when i create my input in aspx page i can use server side event without any problem